Confusion on Lenz's law
Consider the following scenario 
Where a coil is pulled across a magnetic field. Now, as we enter the magnetic field, flux is increasing in a left to right direction. So by Lenz's law the coil generates a magnetic field whose lines create a flux in the right to left direction. This creates a force that pushes the fire to the left as the coil enters the field. So far so good.
But what about the direction of current? It could be either clockwise or anticlockwise.
Either way it would generate a magnetic field which is parellel to the magnetic field denoted by the crosses. But this means that the magnetic field generated by the loop does not counteract the left to right increase in flux? Is that not a contradiction? Also when the coil exits the field the direction in current would flip but the force due to Lenz's law would continue to be to the left. How is that possible?

"Now, as we enter the magnetic field, flux is increasing in a left to right direction." No: the flux through the coil – that is the flux that's relevant to Lenz's law – is increasing. The spatial direction of the flux density is into the page (or screen) – not left to right. Lenz's law tells us that the coil generates flux through itself coming out of the page.

Ok, but then why is there a force to the left? And why does the force continue to be to the left as the loop exits?

In order to generate flux through itself coming out of the page, the induced current in the coil must be anticlockwise. Fleming's left hand motor rule (or the Lorentz force law) shows that the right hand side of the coil experiences a force to the left as the coil enters the external field. I leave it up to you to work out what happens as the coil leaves the external field region.

Applying the right hand rule(Lorentz force)  with the thumb pointing up and the index finger out of the page, I get the middle finger( force) to the right which is a contradiction...What am I missing?

Or wait, are you considering the magnetic field to be the original one(denoted with the X in the question) and not the generated one? In that case why? Won't the generated magnetic field and the orignal one cancel each other out?

Or is it not possible for a coil to exert a self force?

"are you considering the magnetic field to be the original one (denoted with the X in the question) [...]?" Yes. [Just to make sure: you do know that the x symbols in the diagram represent the crossed tail-feathers of retreating arrows, denoting that the external field is away from you, into the page?] "Won't the generated magnetic field and the orignal one cancel each other out?" No: for one thing the coil won't produce a uniform field over its cross-section.

"Or is it not possible for a coil to exert a self force?" The sides of the coil WILL exert forces on each other because of the induced current. These forces, according to Newton's third law, come in equal and opposite pairs, so there is no RESULTANT force on the coil due to these self-forces. But the force pairs do constitute stresses, which tend to collapse the coil.

Thanks, I think that answers my question.

The loop on the left which is entering the region of magntic field has a current $i$ induced in it which oppose that motion as shwon below.

As the loop leaves the region of magnetic field the induced current in the loop is in a clockwise direction (up in the left hand side of the loop) which produces a magnetic field out of the screen in opposition to the decreasing flux through the loop.
The force on the left hand side of the loop due to the interaction of the induced current and the external magnetic field is to the left again opposing the motion of the loop.

Actually the flux is increasing inside page so induced current is anticlockwise to  resist increase of flux inside page.. ( bcoz anticlockwise induced current increase flux outside page ) ...
Net force on loop is 0 after it is fully entered..
